# Add EventListener on new sheet vba

Tags: excel, vba, events

I have to create an Excel sheet automatically with vba.

Some cells need an Onchange Event Listener and I wanted to know if there is a way to create this Event Listener automatically by calling a macro instead of writing it down everytime in every sheet code ?

Thank you

Comment: You can programatically write vba if you Trust the VBA object model (In settings). You could then use the `ThisWorkbook_NewSheet` Event to add this code to all new sheets on their creation

Comment: Would you consider writing the code just once at Application event level within the `_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` routine? You could just test if the `Sh` object is one of your desired sheets?

Comment: You could use an addin also to handle this using the same methods above.

Comment: Thank you all for help but I'm a begginner in vba so I don't really understand what you are saying and dunno where to put the code or what to do. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this question because I think it might have some relevance to quite a few other people too, so the code below should get you started in the right direction.

However, there is an expectation on this site that you try to help yourself at least to the same extent as we try to help you. The commenters have mentioned the `VBA Object Model`, `Application Events` and `AddIns`. It shouldn't be beyond the wit of most people to then research these key words (say with a google search). It's not really acceptable simply to say you "dunno where to put the code or what to do", and, in all honesty, doesn't particularly motivate people to help you - put another way, you're pretty lucky to get an answer with that post and comment.

I don't want to get into a huge comment exchange on exactly how to code your specific case. The code here is an example and I would expect you then to research it further. So here goes ...

Insert a class module (research that if you don't know how) and name it - I've called mine *cApp*. This will enable you to access the Application object and capture its events, like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mApp As Application
Private mSheetList As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Create instance of the sheet collection
    Set mSheetList = New Collection

    'If you wanted to add any existing sheets to be checked for changes,
    'then you'd do it here.
    'Just for an example, I'm using any existing sheets whose name contains "LoP".
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If InStr(ws.Name, "LoP") > 0 Then
            mSheetList.Add ws
        End If
    Next

    'Create instance of Application
    Set mApp = Application
End Sub

Private Sub mApp_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Test if the changed sheet is in our list.

    'Check if the Sh object is a worksheet.
    If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet Then

        'Loop through out list of sheets and see if the Sh object is in the list.
        For Each ws In mSheetList
            If Sh Is ws Then

                'Check if the changed range is in the desired range of your sheet.
                'In this example, we'll say it has to been in the range "A1:B2".
                If Not Intersect(Target, ws.Range("A1:B2")) Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox ws.Name & "!" & Target.Address(False, False) & " has changed."
                End If

                Exit For

            End If
        Next

    End If


End Sub

Private Sub mApp_WorkbookNewSheet(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Sh As Object)

    'A new sheet has been created so add it to our sheet list.
    If Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
        If TypeOf Sh Is Worksheet Then
            mSheetList.Add Sh
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

You then want to create an instance of this class. I've done it in a standard `Module`:

```
Option Explicit

Private oApp As cApp

Public Sub RunMe()

    'Create instance of your app class
    Set oApp = New cApp

End Sub
```

You'd then call the `RunMe` routine somewhere within your code. You might choose to do this in your `Workbook_Open()` event, but it could be anywhere of your choosing.

I've commented the code pretty heavily so you can see what it's doing and you can always research each of the keywords if you're not sure what they're doing.

Comment: Well after some research I found out how to complete the code. Thank you that's pretty tough but it work !